# I want to populate DropDownList2 from the result of DropDownList1 and delete the row in asp.net 2012 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used the below code. It displays all the fields in the 1st dropdown as required. the second drop down should contain all the values of the fields selected in the 1st dropdown.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + " FROM servers", sqlcon);
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = com.ExecuteReader();
DropDownList4.Items.Clear();

while (dr.Read())
{
  DropDownList4.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString()));
}
```

The delete operation should be performed based on the two dropdown values.

```
SqlCommand delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM servers WHERE '" +DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text+ "' = '"+ DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value +"'" , sqlcon);
```

It is not showing any errors, but it is not giving expected results. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** use inline queries in code. This may yield `SQLInjection` attacks. Always use parameterized sql stored procedures.

Try this:

Set both `Text` and `Value` in `ListItem`

```
 while (dr.Read())
    {
      DropDownList4.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString(),dr[0].ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: is right, inline sql is never good. Use stored procs. If you want to go a step further, keep all your sql calls in one class.